# Adding text to a hover over image

Tags: css, image, hover

I am new to CSS and have been experimenting for the last few weeks. I have created a CSS hover over image for a button, but need to add text over the top of it.

For some reason every time I try to add it, the text is placed in a div box below and doesn't get placed in the area I wish (Over the top of the Image)

I have added my code to JSfiddle below, any help would be appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/leeyum8721/LGh4Z/

```
 <style>
    .img3 {
        width: 313px;
        height: 177px;
    }
    .StjohnsPageButton {
        width:313px;
        height:177px;
        display:block;
    }
    #StjohnsButton {
        background-image:url('http://www.ovoma.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Venues-Page_03-2.jpg');
    }
    .StjohnsPageButton:hover {
        background-position:left 177px;
    }
    </style>

<div class="img3 left">
<a href="" id="StjohnsButton" class="StjohnsPageButton"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi ,i cant understand what you exactly want in that.

Comment: Can you put your text, that is shown wrong in the fiddle?

Comment: Do you want to add some text after image every time when user hovers on it?

Comment: Hi there, No the text has to stay there all the time. I have added a picture below in the imgur link of how I want it to look. http://imgur.com/aM2g4hn. Everytime I try to use a <h3> css tag it goes below my image, when I want to it to appear over the top of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LGh4Z/10/)

ALL that you needed was z-index

**EDIT 1:** [UPDATED FIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/LGh4Z/12/)

**EDIT 2:** This is to go further and make the image responsive

***[FIDDLE1](http://jsfiddle.net/LGh4Z/15/)***
***[FIDDLE2](http://jsfiddle.net/LGh4Z/16/)***

The first fiddle make the whole image clickable. The second one makes only the words ***"St John's Hotel"*** clickable

Notice that i have added some CSS for the second fiddle so that the text remains white in color and does not have an underline beacuse it is a link

```
.textoverimage a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: What was your hover effect doing?

Comment: Originally, the background image was not shifting, but you fixed it now, so you are good.

Comment: @AnaMaria thats perfect, thank you so much. I am still fiddling with the code though, as I need the image to link to another page, I'm not exactly sure where to place the <a href> for it. I keep making the text into a link instead of the actual image.

Comment: if you want the whole image to be clickable place the <a ref> outside of the main <div>.. If you want only the text inside the image to be clickable place it outside the <p> tag

Comment: Check the second EDIT now

Comment: @LiamPerry, if you think my solution is the answer dont forget to mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the new jsfiddle check it out.. jsfiddle.net/LGh4Z/9/